# Awesome font in button menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs, font-awesome, extjs5

I am using awesome font in my app.

The problem is in the button menu.

I usually use: `iconCls: 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg'`

I change the icon color onmouseover with CSS like this: `.x-btn-over {color: #9B30FF;}`

But this does not work in button menu items.

I must use: `glyph: 'xf0ad@FontAwesome'`

Problem: I can not change the icon color onmouseover.

I tried as mentioned in this post, but it did not work in my case:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287651-HOW-TO-change-glyph-color-in-menu

I would appreciate suggestions to solve.

```
       Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text      : 'Menu button',
        renderTo  : Ext.getBody(),
        arrowAlign: 'bottom',
        menu      : [
            {text: 'Item 1', glyph: 'xf0ad@FontAwesome'}, // it works
            {text: 'Item 2', iconCls: 'fa fa-wrench fa-lg'},// does not work
        ]
       });
```

EDITED:

It is the first time I tried to make a fiddle with css.

It did not go well ...

Anyway, I put all the code in app.js file

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/138k

Works fine:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/138o

Comment: The menu items aren't buttons and don't share the same CSS class names - when you mouse over an item it adds the class `x-menu-item-active`.  The documentation also lists a SASS variable called [`$menu-item-active-glyph-color`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-css_var-S-menu-item-active-glyph-color).

Comment: Thanks Emissary. Unfortunately, does not work in the button menu items.  I also tried: .x-menu-item-icon-default .x-menu-item-icon .x-menu-item-glyph { color:  #FF0000;}   unsuccessful. Also I can not change the opacity of 0.5 to 1.

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: `.x-menu-item-active .x-menu-item-icon-default` [works fine for me](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/138h), you're going to have to provide an example.  It sounds like you've misunderstood [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Thanks Emissary your fiddle works fine. I will rebuild my app using  sencha app watch to see if I identify the problem.